# How to show a Listview below Recylerciew inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout in which I am using Linearlayout and orientation of this layout is vertical. I am showing toolbar and Recylerview in this layout. I want to show Listview below this Recyclerview. When I am adding the listview below recyclerview in the layout, the listview don't get display.

I have tried this using Relative layout also using layout_below property, but the listview is not coming in this case also.

How can I do this, please help me.

Comment: please post your code so that we can figure out your issue.

Comment: Please check the above code once, the whole code is in RelativeLayout.

Comment: please post your full xml file

Comment: This is the whole code, the code is in below Relative Layout.

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

Comment: This is the whole code and the above code is in below Relative layout.
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

Comment: try to change the (height) wrap content to specific value or use weightsum for layouts.

Comment: change the relative layout to Linear layout

Comment: I have changed the RelativeLayout in LinearLayout also with orientation vertical, but it do not show the listview below recylerview.

Comment: change the relative layout to linear layout and mention the recyclerview height like ex :400dp or something like that also mention the height values for listview and remaining layouts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96026/discussion-between-rajsundar-and-prithniraj-nicyone).

Comment: I have tried it by adding the listview as the footer of recyclerview, but it still does not work. Can someone please tell me how can I achieve it. Thank you so much in advanced.